# How to save createdAt updatedAt as Date type instead of String type with Sailsjs 1.0 and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, aggregation-framework, waterline, sails-mongo

Sails 1.x saves createdAt and updatedAt as **string** instead of **Date** type with mongodb.

the problem is that i have aggregation pipes with $add (adding days, months, secs, etc...) with the createdAt and updatedAt fields and Mongodb throws error that $add only accept type of **numeric** or **date**, not string.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your model definition for the date colum uses type 'ref' and columnType 'datetime':

```
date: { type: 'ref', columnType: 'datetime', required: true },
number: { type: 'number', columnType: 'float', defaultsTo: 0 }
```